# how to count appearance of '1' in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file consisting of multiple lines of

```
b b b b b b ... b
```

where `b` is binary which can be `0` or `1`. How can I write bash scripts to count number of `1`s in the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < myfile.txt | grep -c '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
tr -dc 1 < inputfile | wc -c
```